# how to implement chat application in android?

Tags: android

i am developing chat application in android...
i got some exception when i run my application

```
08-27 18:05:29.545: WARN/System.err(809): java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore jks implementation not found
08-27 18:05:29.565: WARN/System.err(809):     at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:134)
08-27 18:05:29.565: WARN/System.err(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.ServerTrustManager.<init>(ServerTrustManager.java:61)
08-27 18:05:29.589: WARN/System.err(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:1246)
08-27 18:05:29.594: WARN/System.err(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:313)
08-27 18:05:29.594: WARN/System.err(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
08-27 18:05:29.604: WARN/System.err(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:76)
```

and also getting verify exception but i checked my username and password...

```
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809): java.lang.VerifyError: org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:303)
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:395)
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at com.sample.test.HelloFormStuffActivity$1.run(HelloFormStuffActivity.java:41)
08-27 18:05:31.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(809):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jks is not implemented in android. Change it to bks instead.

Comment: Change the line where you get your keystore instance, e.g:

KeyStore.getInstance("bks");

Comment: i get this code from this url
http://credentiality2.blogspot.com/2010/03/xmpp-asmack-android-google-talk.html

Comment: Then the problem is in the libs used in that sample, but try this: http://blog.jayway.com/2008/11/21/give-back-my-xmpp-in-android/

Comment: Hmm I'm using this: http://code.google.com/p/asmack/downloads/list and I still get the error